# QTreeView - how to tell if a drag/drop event is a reorder or a move between parents?

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qtreeview, qabstractitemview

I have subclasses of `QTreeView` and `QAbstractItemModel` and currently I'm using drag-drop to move items from one parent index to another.  I want to also add the ability to rearrange the order of items within the same parent index.  When the user drops an item in-between two other items, I need to determine whether the drop should be into, or in-between them.  I would also like to draw a dark line between the two items as the mouse is moved, to hint as to what will occur, similar to many other tree-type views (e.g. file explorers on most operating systems) as in the attached pictures:

Drag into an existing item:

[image: drag into]

Insert between two existing items:

[image: drag in-between]

Does Qt automate this part of drag/drop behavior, or do I have to manually calculate the mouse position relative to the edge of the tree item?  Also, how can I draw a temporary line between two items in the `QTreeView`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did almost the same thing some time ago, and I can think of 3 things :

- you will have to reimplement your `dropEvent()`, and maybe your `dragMoveEvent()`;
- to check where you are dropping an item, use [dropIndicatorPosition()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#dropIndicatorPosition);
- to show the drop indicator, use [setDropIndicatorShown(bool)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#showDropIndicator-prop).

Here's a very minimal example of what I was doing.

In the `dragMoveEvent()`, I was showing the drop indicator. This way, you will always have your drop indicator shown when you're dragging an object.

```
void MyTreeView::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent* event)
{
    setDropIndicatorShown(true);
    QTreeView::dragMoveEvent(event);
}
```

In the `dropEvent()`, I was managing each case, that's to say if the item I was dragging was on another item, above it, below it or on the viewport. Then, according to it, I was managing my own drop, and at the end of the event, I hid the drop indicator.

```
void MyTreeView::dropEvent(QDropEvent* event)
{
    bool dropOK = false;
    DropIndicatorPosition dropIndicator = dropIndicatorPosition();

    switch (dropIndicator)
    {
    case QAbstractItemView::AboveItem:
        dropOK = true;
        break;
    case QAbstractItemView::BelowItem:
        dropOK = true;
        break;
    case QAbstractItemView::OnItem:
        dropOK = false;
        break;
    case QAbstractItemView::OnViewport:
        dropOK = false;
        break;
    }
    if(dropOK)
    {
        // Here, you need to manage yourself the case of dropping an item
    }
    setDropIndicatorShown(false); // hide the drop indicator once the drop is done
}
```

---

*"Bonus"* : you can access the drop indicator in your own style by the [PrimitiveElement](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#PrimitiveElement-enum) `PE_IndicatorItemViewItemDrop`. 
You can see how to customize it [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/35443-Customize-drop-indicator-in-QTreeView) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4755261/5653461).